# How to populate expandable listview from sqlite database

Tags: expandablelistview

I have referred some links but i didn't get good stuff. I have a table in sqlite which has 4 cols. id,menu_name,description,amount. I want that the menu_name should be the parent and description and amount should be the child populated from database. When i will click on particular menu_name it should expand and show the details of that menu. How to do it? I didn't get good tutorial for this