# SQlite to Expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have similar question to this
[How to populate expandable listview from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687224/how-to-populate-expandable-listview-from-sqlite-database)

At the moment, I have an sqlite database, and I've used the SimpleAdapter just fine.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> getType = db.getType();

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, getType, R.layout.entry, 
                   new String[] {"a","b","c","d"},
                   new int[] {R.id.a, R.id.b, R.id.c,R.id.d});
```

Now however, I want to use an expandable list view with the child populated from the database.

Something Like this:

|Header|

a|b|c|d

a|b|c|d

|Header2|

a|b|c|d

a|b|c|d

Any advice on how I should start?

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html

Comment: You should first populate the headers. For each header, then, populate its children. Then add the adaper to the ExpandableListView. It's not **too** hard.

Comment: Check this post http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-expandablelistview-using.html. It may help U